# HTML/CSS Content/Sidebar Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple website with a content div and a sidebar div but the sidebar div is pushing somethings down in my content div, even though its outside. I believe this is an easy fix, but it has been hard to search for this exact scenario.

I created a jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/WRs7L/.

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main"> 
      <div id="sidebar"></div>  
      <div id="content">
        <div id="resume">
          <section id="employment" class="part">
            <h2>Employment</h2>
              <section class="item">
                <div class="info cf">
               <div class="left">
            <span class="title">Title</span>
            <span class="employer">Employer</span>
            <span class="group">Group</span>                
              </div>
              <div class="right">
            <span class="dates">Date</span>
            <span class="location">Location</span>              
              </div>       
                  <div style="clear: both;"></div>   
                </div> 
                <div class="content">
                 <ul>
                   <li>Item 1</li>
                   <li>Item 2</li>
                   <li>Item 3</li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </section>    
           </section>    
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the width and heights of the two divs you wish to sit side by side.

I think you problem is that you arn't specifying widths/heights to the element which you want to sit next to the sidebar.
For instance if you have a page which is 1000px in width, you would create two divs e.g

```
<div id="side1"></div>
<div id="side2"></div>
```

Then apply the css to make them sit side by side:

```
#side1
  {
    width:49%;
    height:500px;
    float:left
    margin-right:1%;
    clear:none;
   }

 #side2   {
    width:50%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
   }
```

Comment: I do specify the widths in my real code and am still getting these same problems.  I just wanted to put the minimum code up to replicate my problem.  The JSFiddle link does a better job showing what I mean.